# Infinite scrolling in the opposite direction from bottom to up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible? Because when the page content is automatically navigated first down, and during that it touches the top. I would like to have in fixed overflow div where the content should automatically start right from the bottom. And then when you scroll up to read more content.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Could you make your question more concrete? Did you try implementing this and do you have some code to share with us?

Comment: Sounds like a horrible UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible but you have to script the scrolling behaviour:

pseudocode:

```
oldHeight = heightBeforeLoad
<load stuff>
scrollTop = scrollTop + (heightAfterLoad - oldHeight)
```

you basicly automagically scroll the page down with the height of the new content.